# Why can't I set a max-width for Instagram iFrames in my scss files?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to keep my Instagram embeds under a certain width, and I've tried putting into my scss files a max-width, which NEVER have gotten into the file. The only way I can get it to my preferred with is to use inspector and manually change it but that doesn't do me any good. Here is the HTML with the part I wanna change highlit:
[image: the structure]

I wanted to do

```
iframe[class^="instagram-media"]{
    width:328px;
}
```

but that doesn't work. Neither did

```
iframe{
    max-width:328px
}
```

How can I get this?

Comment: please post the code not the picture so I can test and see what is wrong

Comment: what's wrong with just helping me get the right css code to get the element I need?

Comment: again you don't even need css to do this you can simple assign width and height iframe attributes, make it simple.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto there is nowhere in my code where an iFrame element is directly placed.

Comment: the blue part in the photo

Comment: @OtávioBarreto I meant in my source code. Clearly, there's a plugin somewhere that generates it but I should be able to deal with it in my css files

Comment: what do you use? wordpress or something like it?, post the code of your plugin so, this way I can modify the iframe generation style

Comment: yes, I use wordpress. Is it set in there?

Comment: yes it's  probably some plugin or theme function that has the iframe setup, post your theme and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mid that width and height you dont need css to apply on iframe you can simple assign to width and height attributes, like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="500px" height="500px">
 </iframe>
```

Just change  `width=""` and  `height=""` iframe attributes for your need.

Comment: yea but nowhere in my code does the Instagram iFrame show up like that

Comment: post your code and I will fix it, post in text not in image format I can't edit because it's in image format, you also don't need to post full code, only the iframe part